# What does ReliabilityContractAttribute do?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, attributes

Does it do anything at all or it is only for documentation. If it is only for documentation, why documentation doesn't document it?

For example, these two static methods of `System.Array`:

```
[ReliabilityContract(Consistency.MayCorruptInstance, Cer.MayFail)]
public static void Copy(Array sourceArray, Array destinationArray, int length)

[ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.Success)]
public static void ConstrainedCopy(Array sourceArray, int sourceIndex, Array destinationArray, int destinationIndex, int length)
```

Their generated MSDN documentation doesn't even mention that [`Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4yx47a1.aspx) or [`ConstrainedCopy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.constrainedcopy.aspx) are annotated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe they're used for constrained execution regions too, so the CLR knows what it can do safely. There are certain things that your code can't do within the CER, and in return the CLR guarantees that certain out-of-band exceptions aren't thrown.

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228973(v=vs.110).aspx) has some more details.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Linked to an MSDN page which looks reasonable; I don't know whether the MSDN *magazine* page still exists somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.constrainedexecution.reliabilitycontractattribute.aspx):

> The ReliabilityContractAttribute
>   attribute provides a mechanism for you
>   to document your code, and to indicate
>   what type of reliability guarantees
>   you can make in the face of
>   exceptional conditions that could
>   potentially lead to an inconsistent
>   state. In this context, exceptional
>   conditions are defined as asynchronous
>   exceptions that can be generated at
>   run time by the common language
>   runtime, such as aborted threads,
>   out-of-memory situations, and stack
>   overflows. You can apply the
>   ReliabilityContractAttribute attribute
>   to assemblies, types, and methods.
>
> Use this attribute with the
>   Consistency enumeration to define a
>   reliability contract by documenting
>   the level of reliability in a
>   particular piece of code.

Comment: Yes. I have read this. So, why this documentation is ignored?